# How to create guides to off-screen objects?

Tags: gui, three.js

I've played Metroid Blast on Wii U, and would like to build one of its features in a three.js game.

The feature is: if an opponent is out of view, a guide is displayed showing the direction of the opponent.

An example of it is here:

[image]

([Image source](http://www.wiiuonly.com/2012/11/nintendo-land-metroid-blast-animal.html))

Notice the small circles with arrows in the left side.

How could I have a similar feature in my game?

Answer (score 3):

For each opponent/object/destination to display:

- Project it's worldspace location to view-space (MV)
- Flatten the Z to 0
- Normalize the direction to unit-length
- Multiply by "HUD" radius (world/view-space units)
  (the linked image looks like they might have used aspect ratio, instead, to stretch circle into an ellipse)
  (i.e. scale by `(widthFactor, heightFactor, 0)` instead of `1.0f`)

[image]

I may not be able to provide the code to "find opponents within the proper range" (using three) (I'm betting you can)